# How to implement swipe on radial menu to make the menu move out and in of the screen

Tags: android, radial, multi-window

I have implemented radial menu functionality in my android app. It is semicircular radial menu which is present in the left hand side of the screen.

Now I want to implement swipe on it so that I could swipe it out and in whenever I want to toggle between the menus.

Similar to the multi window functionality we can see in the new galaxy devices....

When I would swipe out, a small image or hint would be present in the extreme left to know about the presence of the menu..so when I would swipe right again the radial menu would come out ....

Image of my radial menu is attached ..
Is there particular api I need to refer?

I

[image: Radial Menu Image]